# custom header in multitenant application

Tags: view, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a multi-tenant application with a custom header, basically the logo of the customer and some links are in there.

The header is visible in most modules, but needs to read the logo settings from the database. How do I organise this best?

If I use a component, I have to paste it into all modules. Can I centralise a slot better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

First, a [component_slot](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_component_slots) (link goes to 1.2 documentation but it's ok in 1.4). You defined it in for an app and you can re-define it for a specific module.

Second, a [basic component](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/19#chapter_19_language_switching). It will perform always the same thing and you can't re-define it. You don't have to paste it in all module, you can call a component from a module X in the template of module Y.